# Constructors and Destructors of Objects

Tags: c++

I'm wrapping up my C++ course and I am repeatedly asked: how many times does a constructor/deconstructor get called in an objects life.

The simple answer to me seems like only once, and as far as I know, that's the case, but is there a case where they could be called more than once?

Comment: Does a delegating constructor count as two constructor calls?

Comment: One thing that can help you is to *play* with code that can experiment on. Take [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/dVbUxK) as an example, try to make all kinds of things, and look at the output, it should get you the information that you want :)

Comment: It actually depends on the type of object.  The lifetime of an object that is an instance of a class with non-trivial initialisation (i.e. a non-trivial constructor) is considered to begin when initialisation is complete (i.e. after completion of the constructor).   For other objects (classes with a trivial constructor, non-class objects, arrays) the lifetime begins when storage is allocated.   The lifetime of an object with non-trivial destructor is considered to end before the destructor is executed, but lifetime of other objects is considered to end when its storage is released or reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Constructor is called at most once per lifetime. Sometimes there is no need to call a constructor for example in the case the constructor is trivial.

Comment: would just like to add that the Destructor can also be called 0 times, if the constructor failed.

Comment: Even if the class has no constructor, the default constructor is auto-generated during compilation, and it is called.

Comment: Destructor also will not be called if the ctor was called implicitly via new (or new []), but delete (or delete []) was never explicitly called.

Comment: @M.M changed the wording to hopefully be technically correct.

Comment: What about delegating constructors, do they count as several ctor calls?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wouldn't count it as several constructor calls. There's one construction which executes code that is divided into separate blocks.